# Get full image array

Tags: images, advanced-custom-fields, media-library

When I use Advanced Custom Fields I can return the full image array of an upload. Is there a native WordPress way to get the full image array for any image in the Media Library by image ID? I can find ways to get the alt text and a specific image size, but not the array itself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "full array" is constructed by Advanced Custom Fields from various sources. It's not a format that occurs natively in WordPress.

If you want to output an image tag for an image with all the correct attributes, just use the ID with [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/). That returns an HTML `<img>` tag with the `src`, `width`, `height`, `alt`, `srcset`, `sizes` and `class` all populated. You can add or change attributes to the tag using the 4th argument:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image(
    $attachment_id,
    'large',
    false
    [
        'class'          => 'custom-class',
        'data-attribute' => 'custom-attribute-value',
    ]
);
```

To be honest, if your goal is to ultimately get an `<img>` tag, then even with ACF you should return an ID and use this function.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct as thanks for confirming there's no native function... 
I completely disagree about using that function instead of ACF no matter what though: ACF's array can be super useful - that's why they created it! Ultimately I created my own version of their array to use for native WordPress, which suits my purposes.

Comment: What are your purposes?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Autoload/Composer you can use `$image = \acf_get_attachment( $attachment_id );` to get an acf image array. If not I guess you can use `require_once()` to load your `plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/includes/api/api-helpers.php`, however I haven't tested this yet.